# Bezier evaluation in O(n)

Tags: java, performance, algorithm

The really stupid way to evaluate bezier curves is with recursion, which is \$O(2^n)\$, which can be lowered to \$O(n^2)\$ with memoization. De Casteljau's algorithm improves on this, and is still \$O(n^2)\$ but faster.

I misinterpreted De Casteljau's and thought it was the Bernstein form:

$$\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}{\binom{n}{i}p_i (1-t)^{n-i-1} t^i}$$

Where there are \$n\$ control points including the start and end named \$p_0, p_1,p_2, \dots, p_{n-1}\$.

Calculating the combination is normally \$O(n)\$ which would make this algorithm as a whole \$O(n^2)\$ since there are \$n\$ terms to sum, however, there is a cheat:

$$\binom{n}{k}=\prod_{i=1}^{k}{\frac{n+1-i}{k}}$$

We can store the result after each iteration, resulting in the entire sequence calculated in \$O(n)\$ time, making the algorithm as a whole \$O(n)\$.

\$2\leq n\leq 5\$ is the general use case (2 and 4 probably actually), so it's hardcoded. For \$n\geq 6\$, which uses this algorithm, I've done a ridiculous number of optimizations.

The smallest `double` increment (one mantissa bit) is \$2.2E{-16}\$, and based on some quick benchmarks with random data it never was more inaccurate than \$1E{-14}\$, so the inaccuracy is acceptable.

For very large \$n\$ (hundreds, 1200 was where I first saw it) the combination function exceeded the max value for `double`s, causing the algorithm to return `NaN`, whereas De Casteljau's, though much slower, returned what was more or less the correct value.

The final code:

```
public static double bezier2(double a,double b,double t){
    //Total of 3 floating point operations
    //      1 2  3
    return a+t*(b-a);
}

public static double bezier(double t,double... ds){
    return bezier(ds,t);
}

public static double bezier(double[] ds,double t){
    int count = ds.length;
    switch(count){
    case 0:throw new IllegalArgumentException("Must have at least two items to interpolate between");
    case 1:return ds[0];
    case 2:return bezier2(ds[0],ds[1],t);
    case 3:{
        double a = ds[0];
        double b = ds[1];
        double c = ds[2];
        double t1 = 1d - t;
        /*
         * Hardcoded for n=3
         * Total of 8+1=9 floating point operations
         *       1  2  3 4  5  6 7 8
         */
        return (a*t1+2d*b*t)*t1+c*t*t;
    }
    case 4:{
        double a = ds[0];
        double b = ds[1];
        double c = ds[2];
        double d = ds[3];
        double t1 = 1d - t;
        /*
         * Hardcoded for n=4
         * Total of 13+1=9 floating point operations
         *       1  2  3 4  5  6  7   8 9 10 11 12 13
         */
        return (a*t1+3d*b*t)*t1*t1+(3d*c*t1+d*t)*t*t;
    }
    case 5:{
        double a = ds[0];
        double b = ds[1];
        double c = ds[2];
        double d = ds[3];
        double e = ds[4];
        double t1 = 1d - t;
        double i = t1*t1;
        double j = t*t;
        double k = t1*t;
        double l = 4d*k;
        /*
         * Hardcoded for n=5
         * Total of 12+5=17 floating point operations
         *       1  2  3  4   5 6   7   8   9 10 11  12
         */
        return (a*i + b*l + 6d*c*j) * i + (d*l + e*j) * j;
    }
    case 6:
    case 7:
    case 8:
    case 9:
    case 10:
    case 11:return decasteljauBezier(ds,t);
    default:{
        double t1 = 1d - t;
        int n1 = count - 1;
        int halfn = (n1>>1)+1;
        int halfn1 = halfn+1;
        double[] choose;
        if(count<29){
            choose = new double[halfn1];
            int[] chooseInt = chooseIntRange(n1,halfn);
            for(int i=0;i<halfn1;i++){
                choose[i]=chooseInt[i];
            }
        }else if(count<60){
            choose = new double[halfn1];
            long[] chooseLong = chooseLongRange(n1,halfn);
            for(int i=0;i<halfn1;i++){
                choose[i]=chooseLong[i];
            }
        }else{
            choose = chooseDoubleRange(n1,halfn);
        }
        double[] terms = new double[count];
        double power = 1d;
        for(int i=0;i<halfn;i++){
            terms[i] = ds[i] * choose[i] * power;
            power *= t;
        }
        for(int i=halfn;i<count;i++){
            terms[i] = ds[i] * choose[n1-i] * power;
            power *= t;
        }
        power = t1;
        for(int i=1;i<count;i++){
            terms[n1-i] *= power;
            power *= t1;
        }
        double sum = 0d;
        for(double v:terms){
            sum += v;
        }
        return sum;
    }
    }
}

public static double decasteljauBezier(double[] ds,double t){
    int n = ds.length;
    double[] result = Arrays.copyOf(ds, n);
    for(int i=n-1;i>0;i--){
        for(int j=0;j<i;j++){
            result[j]+=(result[j+1]-result[j])*t;
        }
    }
    return result[0];
}

public static int[] chooseIntRange(int n,int k){
    int n1 = n+1;
    int product = 1;
    int[] result = new int[k+1];
    result[0] = 1;
    for(int i=1;i<=k;i++){
        product = product*(n1-i)/i;
        result[i] = product;
    }
    return result;
}

public static long[] chooseLongRange(int n,int k){
    int n1 = n+1;
    int product = 1;
    long[] result = new long[k+1];
    result[0] = 1;
    for(int i=1;i<=k;i++){
        product = product*(n1-i)/i;
        result[i] = product;
    }
    return result;
}

public static double[] chooseDoubleRange(int n,int k){
    int n1 = n+1;
    double product = 1d;
    double[] result = new double[k+1];
    result[0] = 1;
    for(int i=1;i<=k;i++){
        product = (product * (n1-i)) / i;
        result[i] = product;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Notes:

1. This was optimized by hand by me, and likely again by the compiler. It would explain how \$2\leq n\leq 5\$ was all roughly the same speed but \$n=6\$ then suddenly was \$\frac{1}{3}\$ of the speed.
2. These numbers aren't randomly chosen. They're based on the max values for `int`s and `long`s. It might be possible to increase these a bit (and therefore improve the algorithm ever so slightly) but I like safety.
3. Semi-in-place De Casteljau's with all the optimizations I could think of. It's pretty fast but still \$O(n^2)\$.

De Casteljau's was faster for \$6\leq n\leq 11\$, so I thought of redirecting. But as it turns out, the extra cost of that single `if` statement and a redirect call meant that it was only worth redirecting for \$6\leq n\leq 9\$. Even that redirect might be gone in the future with more optimizing. It's not like the time isn't comparable for such a small \$n\$.

Beating \$O(n)\$ is definitely impossible, but I'm certain there is a better algorithm out there, or if not, a better way to implement this one. If not even that, surely there are optimizations I've missed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to look at your unit tests, because there's a bad bug in `chooseLongRange`. `int product = 1` should be `long product = 1`.

---

```
    if(count<29){//See note 1
        choose = new double[halfn1];
        int[] chooseInt = chooseIntRange(n1,halfn);
        for(int i=0;i<halfn1;i++){
            choose[i]=chooseInt[i];
        }
    }else if(count<60){//See note 2
        choose = new double[halfn1];
        long[] chooseLong = chooseLongRange(n1,halfn);
        for(int i=0;i<halfn1;i++){
            choose[i]=chooseLong[i];
        }
    }else{
        choose = chooseDoubleRange(n1,halfn);
    }
```

IMO this is excessively complicated. Unless you're reusing `chooseIntRange` and `chooseLongRange` in contexts which require `int[]` or `long[]`, why not make them return `double[]`? And then you can push in the case split for the type to use, exposing a single method and leaving the responsibility in the method where it really belongs.

---

I'm slightly puzzled by "*But as it turns out, the extra cost of that single if statement and a redirect call meant that it was only worth redirecting for 6≤n≤9*". What "single if statement"? Do you mean the overhead of the `switch` table lookup?

---

I get the impression that you care more about performance than numerical analysis, but I think it's worth making this point anyway.

There's an important difference between

```
a + (b - a) * t
```

and

```
a * (1 - t) + b * t
```

If you substitute \$(a, b, t) = (b, a, 1-t)\$ then the second will give you the same result, but the first won't necessarily. In particular, when \$t \approx 1\$ and \$b \ll a\$ the result should be very close to \$b\$, but in the first expression the subexpression \$b - a\$ will lose the precision of \$b\$ and it can't be recovered in the final result.